# Find all methods without documentation (preferably inside a directory) in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to find all the methods without documentation in PhpStorm 10? What I can think of now is using regex, but I don't know how reliable it would be.

`Code Inspect/PHPDoc` section doesn't list any of them.

Ex:
Do not find this:

```
/**
 * This method does something.
 * 
 * @param int $name     A parameter
 * 
 * @returns array       An array of something
 */
public function methodName($name)
{
    return array();
}
```

Find This:

```
public function methodName($name)
{
    return array();
}
```

Or maybe even this:

```
/**
 * @param $name
 * @returns
 */
public function methodName($name)
{
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the inspection you're looking for is "Missing PHPDoc comment", it's disabled by default. You can use [Code | Run Inspection by Name](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/running-inspection-by-name.html) or [Code | Inspect Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/running-inspections.html) to find all of the occurrences. Using these tools you can easily configure the desired scope.